# AsyncTask deprecated from Android R. Any alternatives codes?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-asynctask

Since AsyncTask is deprecated from Android R, i cannot parse or accept a JSON Data from the webhttp://plantplaces.com/perl/mobile/flashcard.pl. So what i did  is. I created a kotlin class named DownloadingObject. Below is the code

class DownloadingObject {

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun downloadJSONDataFromLink(link: String): String {
    val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()

    val url: URL = URL(link)
    val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    try {
        val bufferedInputString: BufferedInputStream =
            BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream)
        val bufferedReader: BufferedReader =
            BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(bufferedInputString))
        // temporary string to hold each line read from the BufferedReader.
        var inputLineString: String?
        inputLineString = bufferedReader.readLine()
        while (inputLineString != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(inputLineString)
            inputLineString = bufferedReader.readLine()
        }
    } finally {
        // regardless of success of Try Block or failure of Try Block, we will disconnect from the URLConnection.
        urlConnection.disconnect()
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

And i have to run this downloading task in the background. Below is the code

inner class DownloadingPlantTask : AsyncTask>() {

```
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): List<Plant>? {


        // Can access background thread. Not user interface thread

        val downloadingObject: DownloadingObject = DownloadingObject()
        var jsonData = downloadingObject.downloadJSONDataFromLink(
            "http://plantplaces.com/perl/mobile/flashcard.pl"
        )

        Log.i("JSON", jsonData)

        return null
    }
```

Please if anyone can provide any alternative codes. I am just a bieginner in Android development.

Comment: "I created a kotlin class named DownloadingObject" -- it would have been simpler to use OkHttp, since it has asynchronous request options (`enqueue()`) built in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve multithreading on Android. Since you're using Kotlin you may want to look into [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html). Some other things out there are the [java.concurrent.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package and [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), but in my opinion Coroutines are more beginner-friendly and they integrate with Android components very well.

With coroutines, your code would look like this:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
suspend fun downloadJSONDataFromLink(link: String): String { ... }

GlobalScope.launch {
    val downloadingObject = DownloadingObject()
    val jsonData = downloadingObject.downloadJSONDataFromLink("http://plantplaces.com/perl/mobile/flashcard.pl")
    Log.i("JSON", jsonData)
}
```

The [suspend](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#extract-function-refactoring) keyword means this function can only be called from a coroutine or from another suspending function.

Also you should consider using your Activity/Fragment's [lifecycle scope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) instead of GlobalScope to avoid memory leaks.